# Constrain the consumption of a web service to certain apps

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, visibility

Is there a way I can configure my asp.net web service to work with only some applications? In other words, I am saying "only these applications have access to this web service and can therefore use it. Others can't".

When other applications tries to discover the service, it shouldn't even show up, or at least it should conceal it web methods.

PS: I am wondering if this scenario is even applicable to the whole concept/domain of web services? Plus, I am asp.net 2.0 oriented, but you can give me answers based on higher framework versions, but be specific...Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at WCF (after all ASMX web services are now regarded as legacy)- there is a whole load of options regarding security configuration. Patterns and Practises have [Security Guidance here](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Application%20Scenarios). It sounds like you are most interested in authorization, so read about [Access Control Mechanisms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733106.aspx).

Also to make the service non discoverable in WCF you just don't expose a MEX endpoint. That doesn't stop clients connecting, but makes it hard for people to work out how to call the service. That said you can also [secure the MEX endpoints](http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2006/08/31/733173.aspx) so that is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put some authorization or login method to initialize usage of webservice?

We control usage of services by explicitly logging into the webservice or provide some authorization token.